# Directive scope got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get an issue with passing data to angular directives inside ng-repeat, it always got undefined. Here are my code

The Controller:

```
angular.module('module').controller('ModuleController', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, MyService) { 
    $scope.getData = function() {
        $scope.data = MyService.myGetRequest(); // returning array of objects
    };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="ModuleController" ng-init="getData()" ng-switch="data.length > 0">
   <div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-switch-when="true">
     <my-directive data="d.object"></my-directive>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('module').directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>' // let's ignore the template for now,
        scope: { data: '=' },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.data); // always undefined
        }
    };
 }]);
```

Service:

```
angular.module('module').factory('MyService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/data/:id', 
        { id: '@_id' }, 
        { 
            myGetRequest: { method: 'GET', isArray: true } 
        });
}]);
```

I thought it was because the `$scope.data` still empty when the template loaded. If yes, anyone know what is the solution? Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT: btw, if I put `<my-directive data="data"></my-directive>` instead of `<my-directive data="d.object"></my-directive>` the `scope.data` is **not** undefined anymore, it will show my array of object from resource.

EDIT2: this `<my-directive data="d"></my-directive>` will also resulting `scope.data` in my directive got `undefined`.

EDIT3: Add service code snippet

Comment: what's the data structure? what's in d.object? could you please set up a plunker or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've edited my questions. 

Is the data structure matter?

Not tried in jsfiddle or plunkr yet, but if I hardcoded my data instead of load it from server, it will seems to work, I've saw some examples with hardcoded data for similiar code.

Comment: Are you sure the `$scope.data` object has a member named `object`? This may explain why you are getting `undefined` inside your directive.

Comment: please see `edit2` in my question post.

Comment: Is `MyService.myGetRequest()` an async request?

Comment: I've add important part of my code, which is previously missing when I first time post here.

Answer (score 0):

I think Shomz found the problem. You should use a promise with async call. Like this:

```
angular.module('module').controller('ModuleController', ['$scope', 'MyService',       
    function($scope, MyService) { 

        $scope.data = [];

        MyService.myGetRequest().$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    }

});
```